# Writing a compatible watchdog kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, watchdog

I am developing a custom watchdog driver for the Beaglebone black SBC. There is an external entity connected to the BBB. It will reset the board if it wont receive a GPIO state change from the BBB within a certain time, that is settable through I2C. From what I have understood so far is that from the Linux software point of view, the `/dev/watchdog` device should be written to in order to refresh the watchdog peripheral, that's clear. Such thing could be done by the watchdog daemon: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-watchdog/

The problem here is that it seems that the refresh interval is hard-coded to 60 seconds. For my application the interval is a lot shorter (about 5 seconds typically) and is settable (from 1 to 10 seconds). In this case I think I would not be able to use the watchdog daemon for the custom wdg driver.

Is there a way around this? Or is my take on this case not even correct?

Comment: You can write your own daemon to serve the watchdog using the watchdog ioctl `WDIOC_KEEPALIVE`. See [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, if you want to use kernel watchdog framework, you can simply write some C code which is petting /dev/watchdog file with your own "watchdog frequency". There is no reason to use watchdog daemon if you have your own reasons.

And, the kernel watchdog framework is hooked into real hardware watchdog which is capable to detect lockup, and generate event based on expiration and if your hardware watchdog "timeout" or "expiration" interval can be tunnable, you can change the time and you can make not to fire for 60 seconds.

Normally, nobody is dealing with watchdog process which is provided by busybox or some other linux pkg. Most likely they are using it as it is. Also, as far as I remember, it is 1 seconds interval.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am not sure either manual refresh will do, since I also need to integrate this with the shutdown and reset functionality. So when reset, halt with watchdog refresh off. When shutdown, halt with watchdog on.